# Plurals config files in Android SDK

Tags: android

Where are the config files that define rules for plurals for each language located in the Android source code? I need to replicate the functionality on another platform and was hoping I could use the Android SDK as a good starting point.

Comment: Does this help you?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals

Comment: Unfortunately not, I know about this page. Thank you ... I am looking for the actual source in the Android itself!

Answer (score 0):

Android probably uses [CLDR Language Plural Rules](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html) through ICU4J

Comment: Hi, although this is useful, I am looking for the actual source code ...